# Freemarker get original template object

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I'm using Spring Boot and Freemarker. I'm loading my template from db using a custom loader:

```
public class ContentDbLoader implements TemplateLoader {

    @Inject
    private TemplateRepository templateRepository;

    @Override
    public void closeTemplateSource(Object templateSource) throws IOException {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public Object findTemplateSource(String name) throws IOException {
        return getTemplateFromName(name);

    }

    @Override
    public long getLastModified(Object templateSource) {
        MyTemplate template = (MyTemplate) templateSource;
        template = templateRepository.findOne(template.getId());
        return template.getLastModifiedDate().toEpochMilli();
    }

    @Override
    public Reader getReader(Object templateSource, String encoding) throws IOException {
        return new StringReader(((Template) templateSource).getContent());
    }


    private MyTemplate getTemplateFromName(String name) {
        //my logic
    }
}
```

My model is:

```
Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "channel", "communicationType", "country_id" }) })
public class Template extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8405971325717828643L;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Channel channel;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CommunicationType communicationType;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String subject;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Lob
    private String content;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String sender;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Country country;
```

As you can see I return a MyTemplate object coming from db. When I get the custom template to precess the text, I do this:

```
contentFreemarkerConfig.getTemplate(CommunicationType.WALLET_BALANCE_THRESHOLD + "|" + Channel.EMAIL, locale)
```

but this line return a `freemarker.template.Template`. I would like to have my original template back in order to avoid to make another query on db to get it.

Is that possible with Freemarker?

Comment: As `TemplateLoader` is for loading the raw source (a stream of characters), not for creating a `Template` object, of course it won't work with this approach. I also don't know what's in `MyTemplate`. (Appending an email address to a template name is also suspicious, as it leads to cache bloat.) What's the higher level goal?

Comment: @ddekany MyTemplate has a content, sender and subjects. All things I need to send an email. I don't append the email address to the name, Channel.EMAIL if the kind of template. I've also Channel.SMS. That's all. So the cache is save ;-) The point to have my object is to read additional informations without the need to do others queries.

Comment: Are `MyTemplate.content`, `sender` and `subjects` like templates themselves? If so, the conventional solution is actually creating 3 templates (`"wallet_blance_email_content.ftlh"`, `"wallet_balance_earth_subject.ftl"`, etc.) There's no "batch loading" feature, though the template cache should mostly shield from the overhead.

Comment: @ddekany I added my bean to the question to clarify. I thought something like that. I am doing already that for content and subject but I thought was weird to do that also for sender or other properties I need. It's true templates are in cache but loading programatically 3 different templates is strange. Even more strange because the "sender" should not be processed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to do here (if I understand it well) is making FreeMarker to cache application domain objects for you. This is not something the standard template loading/caching mechanism was designed for; the template library is a lower level layer that deals with its FreeMarker `Template`-s only. As you need multiple `Template`-s per domain object, you can't even bolt this together with `Template.customAttributes` and a custom `TemplateConfigurerFactory` (which can be used to attach arbitrary objects to `Template`-s based on the `templateSource`). So, I think what you should do is this:

- Use any dedicated caching solution to cache your domain objects. The domain objects can store the `Template` objects directly (multiple of them in your case). Simply create those `Template` objects with the `Template` constructor when you create the domain object for a cache miss. Thus for those `Template`-s FreeMarker's `TemplateLoader` and cache isn't used. As far as they don't need to `#include` or `#import` each other (and thus FreeMarker need to be able to get them), that's fine.
- For the sake of templates that the above templates need to `#include` or `#import` (i.e., common utility templates), set up a `TemplateLoader` and FreeMarker's cache will be used for them. As those are just templates, not some application domain objects, certainly you don't need to do anything tricky. (Furthermore such template are often stored in classpath resources or in a configuration directory, so perhaps you don't even need a `DatabaseTemplateLoader`.)